# Does Linux Kernel 3.5 have the improvement from 3.3?

Tags: linux-kernel, radeon

Some weeks ago I updated to Linux kernel version 3.3 because Radeon Audio HDMI wasn't working on my laptop. The issue was fixed with the upgrade to version 3.3 (Though Suspend still doesn't work)

I recently changed distributions, switching from Ubuntu to Mint and when I wanted to update to 3.3 I saw that 3.5 was out too(i'm not really kernel-aware).

But after updating, my Radeon HDMI Audio stopped working again.

So my question is: for me in logical order kernel 3.5 should have improvements from 3.3, except if it's a completely different branch which I don't know about. So why did it break my system? And is there any (easy) way to get the improvement made to radeon drivers from 3.3 to 3.5 ?

(question already asked on superuser , but someone told me that will be better to move it here)

Comment: So fallback to 3.3, I use a stable kernel and patch it myself

Comment: This question is unanswerable. Of course, 3.5.x has some improvements from 3.3.y. It indubitably also has bugs that weren't in 3.3.y. Rather than ask abstract questions like this, ask about your concrete problem. Tell us exactly what distribution and what version you're running, where you got that other kernel you installed, whether you did any configuration related to your hardware, exactly what hardware version you have, etc. Also read the tips in the [faq#dontask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to boot your kernel with

`radeon.audio=1`

i. e. add it to your Grub boot line.

Comment: indeed that work, i knew this trick but it didn't worked with 3.2 ,so i thought i didn't work with 3.5 either.